# No torque wrench - help needed

Tags: torque, bolts, torque-wrench

I am doing a budget piston rings replacement on my car and I want to tighten the conrods back.
The manual says: 13nm+60°+15°.
The thing is that I only have a 20-60nm wrench.
How tight is that 13nm+60°+15°?
Can I just go with 20nm from the start skipping the angle turn ? (60°+15°)

P.s.: i still have 3 more to remove and wanted to ask if I mark them before removing and tighten back to the mark, will that do ?
Thanks !

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I'm not sure that marking them will do the trick. I confess that I have only used a torque wrench twice in my life. The first time I was rebuilding a gearbox with an ally casing, and before it reached the click I thought "no can't tighten it more." On the second occasion I was inserting the oil drain plug on a m/cycle. Trusting the wrench this time, I stripped the thread. Never again.

Answer (score 3):

What you are planning isn't going to work. You need to torque as specified. Not torquing them correctly will most likely end in catastrophic engine failure. There is a reason why the manuals have such specific procedures.

Your suggestion of marking where they were at and then turning back to that position won't work, either. When tightening the bolts with angles involved, you can't just tighten them back to where they were at, because you have to tighten in stages. If those stages aren't done accurately, you are begging for failure.

The connecting rods are probably the most abused part of the engine. They are required to control the piston going both ways. If you get it even anywhere close to wrong, you're just begging for failure.

Comment: You can probably buy a cheap but effective torque wrench for a value that low for less than $30. If you can't borrow one then you can sell it on used for most of its value once you are done with it. Given they are so cheap why take the risk of not using one?